# Using Spring with App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, spring-mvc

I am struggeling using the basic crud methods with app engine:

My code looks like that:

My CustomerController:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAddCustomerPage(ModelMap model) {
   return "command";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {

    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setEmail(email);
    c.setPassword(password);
    c.setDate(new Date());

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        pm.makePersistent(c);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:command");

}

// get all customers
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listCustomer(ModelMap model) {

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Query q = pm.newQuery(Customer.class);
    q.setOrdering("date desc");

    List<Customer> results = null;

    try {
        results = (List<Customer>) q.execute();

        if (results.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("customerList", null);
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("customerList", results);
        }

    } finally {
        q.closeAll();
        pm.close();
    }

    return "list";

}
```

my mvc-dispatcher-servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.Trium.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and the form I want to proceede in command.jsp:

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" action="add"
                                    method="post">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="control-group">

                                            <!-- Text input-->
                                            <label class="control-label" for="input01">Email:</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input name="email" placeholder="email"
                                                    class="input-xlarge" type="text"
                                                    value="<%=request.getParameter("email")%>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <!-- Text input-->
                                            <label class="control-label" for="input01">Password:</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input name="password" placeholder="password"
                                                    class="input-xlarge" type="text"
                                                    value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
```

When I want to proceede the form from `http://127.0.0.1:8888/command.jsp`. I get:

`http://127.0.0.1:8888/add` 
**Error 404**

In GAE I get:

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/add] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Please help me to find what is wrongly mapped in my application.

**UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value/>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**UPDATE - 2**

```
    Mär 26, 2013 4:59:11 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:11 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:17 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Mar 26 16:59:17 UTC 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:19 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:21 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:25 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:25 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7f5fde46: defining beans [customerController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/list],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.add(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/delete/{key}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.delete(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/update],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.update(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/add],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.getAddCustomerPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/update/{name}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.getUpdateCustomerPage(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/list],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.listCustomer(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.login(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:30 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 18804 ms
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Mar 26 16:59:37 UTC 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3c050a95: defining beans [customerController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7f5fde46
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/list],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.add(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/delete/{key}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.delete(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/update],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.update(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/add],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.getAddCustomerPage(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/update/{name}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.getUpdateCustomerPage(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/list],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.listCustomer(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:37 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Trium.controller.CustomerController.login(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 657 ms
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:38 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:38 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: Server default is running at http://localhost:8888/
Mär 26, 2013 4:59:38 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Mär 26, 2013 5:59:38 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Mär 26, 2013 6:00:11 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Now i am getting a different exception. However, I changed nothing from before;P

```
**WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported**
```

Comment: Can you share your web.xml?

Comment: What is the context root of your application? Also, you don't have a handler method for `/add` with method `POST`, but your form `POST`s to `add`

Answer (score 2):

Can you also add the server log when you startup your AppEngine app in your IDE please? 
Spring logs all the URL mappings on startup.

Also in your context:component-scan config, your base package has an uppercase character in it ?

```
com.Trium.controller
```

I'm trying to guess here since I don't know CustomerController's package.

Comment: well that's not necessary a good practice to have uppercase chars in your packages but it's not harmful... I think @Sotirios Delimanolis has your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I feel you are not returning the login page when localhost is actually called. You need to add the following controller mapping to load homepage.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String indexPage(ModelMap map) {
   return "login";
}
```

Now access your localhost:8888 as your login page.

Try returning the name of the page instead of returning the URL.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAddCustomerPage(ModelMap model) {
  return "command";
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer! However, when I do that I also get: `Error 405 Request method 'POST' not supported`

Comment: @maximus you are missing one small thing instead of returning the page of **/add** url. Please return the name of the JSP Page.

Answer (score 2):

You have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAddCustomerPage(ModelMap model) {
   return "command";
}
```

which handles `GET` requests. But your command.jsp form does a `POST` to `add`

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" action="add" method="post">
```

So you need another handler method to handle that action. It appears to me you already have that in the other handler method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {

    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.setEmail(email);
    c.setPassword(password);
    c.setDate(new Date());

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        pm.makePersistent(c);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:command");

}
```

Change your form to `POST` to `/list`

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" action="list" method="post">
```

Also, you shouldn't do `redirect:command`. That basically makes a new request to `localhost:8888/command` which doesn't exist. Do it to `redirect:add` which will call the handler method above and render `command.jsp`.